# Deleting several rows in table of DB

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

I am using code-generator. I have two tables. In one table I have user_id an several docs of this user_id. In second table a have docs of this user_id, but without user_id and I have to delete these docs.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have *some* criteria about the user whose documents you want to delete, just not the foreign key? Just use a [semi-join](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/joined-tables/join-type-semi/), which you can use in `DELETE` statements as well.

Assuming your search criteria is something like the `username`:

#### In SQL

```sql
DELETE FROM docs
WHERE docs.user_id IN (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM user
  WHERE username = ?
)
```

#### In Java

```java
// Assuming the usual static import:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

// Then write:
ctx.deleteFrom(DOCS)
   .where(DOCS.USER_ID.in(
       select(USER.USER_ID)
       .from(USER)
       .where(USER.USERNAME.eq(username))
   ))
   .execute();
```